# Why my program is not working fine? What's the problem with this code? Can anybody tell me?

Tags: c, debugging, error-handling, cs50

This is code I've written in **ide.cs50.io**
When I run it by using the following inputs, it gets stuck when I enter end_size=100

```
$ ./population
Start size: 20
End size: 1
End size: 10
End size: 100
Years: 20
```

The Actual code is:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // TODO: Prompt for start size

    int start_size;
    do
    {
        start_size = get_int("Start Size: ");
    }
    while(start_size < 9);

    // TODO: Prompt for end size

    int end_size;
    do
    {
        end_size = get_int("End Size: ");
    }
    while (end_size < start_size);

    // TODO: Calculate number of years until we reach threshold

    int year = 0;

    while (start_size != end_size)
    {
        start_size = start_size + (start_size / 3) - (start_size / 4);
        year++;
    }

    // TODO: Print number of years

    printf("Years: %i \n", year);

}
```

*can anybody help me to fix the issue?*

Comment: I don't think     "do
    {
        end_size = get_int("End Size: ");
    }" is needed at all. maybe its needed i don't know.

Comment: @drescherjm And, for the given input values (20 and 100), that while loop jumps from 96 to 104, then goes on (eventually) to overflowing integers, and so on *ad nauseam*.

Comment: ... most likely needs `while (start_size < end_size)` instead of `while (start_size != end_size)` ??

Comment: @drescherjm: That's why the first `while` loop exists, to make sure `start_size` is at least `9`.  That way `start_size / 3` will be at least `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `start_size < end_size` instead of `start_size != end_size` - for the inputs you gave, `start_size` never equals `100` exactly - it goes from `96` to `104`.